# Java res api, send image to client

Tags: java, image

I'm working on rest client app using spring boot, now i need to send images to client. What i want to do is to save images in my PC and return path of appropriate image to client like `

```
  Request=`users/user/image/<userId>
  Response = F://eclipse//workspace//My2048//title.ico
```

But in my opinion it will not work because it can't be used by URL class to get image. Is it any alternative ways?

Comment: It should be in `http` url .You can serve as a url using `Tomcat` but need to configure in server.xml.

Comment: Can i  get access to this folder using http?

Comment: yes it is possible using tomcat.I have done this way .